# Spring boot input validation for list of strings only returns first invalid value

Tags: json, spring-boot, bean-validation

We are using Spring boot's Hibernate Bean validation to validate my controller's input request value which contains a list of Strings. We use a regular expression to validate each String in the list. The RegEx works, but it only returns one FieldError even when the list contains multiple invalid values.

```
class MyIncomingRequest {
   @Schema(example = "[\"3FA6P0H71HR224953\"]")
   @NotEmpty(message = "Vin cannot be empty")
   private List<@Valid @Size(min=17,max=17) @Pattern(regexp = someRegEx) String> vins;
}

class MyResponse {
   List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I catch the validation errors in an Exception Handler in the controller:

```
@ExceptionHandler
public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> handleException(MethodArgumentNotValidException e) {
   MyResponse response = new MyResponse();
   for (FieldError fieldError : e.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()) {
      errors.add(fieldError.getDefaultMessage();
   }
}
```

The problem is that we never see more than one FieldError, even when we test this with input JSON that contains multiple invalid input Strings. For example, assume the following two values are not valid:

```
{ "vins" : ["Z0123456789123456", "B0123456789123456"] }
```

We will get a FieldError for the first input value, but never both of them. Why is this? I have seen several examples of code that loops through all of the FieldErrors, so I assume that validation can be performed on every element of the incoming list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get all errors with `e.getBindingResult().getAllErrors()` and make sure that you didn't enabled [hibernate's validator fail fast](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=6.1#section-fail-fast)